# Why does Matlab say this is not an integer?

Tags: matlab

I want to sum over different columns of a matrix.

```
J = (1 / (2*m))*symsum(theta * transpose(X(i,:)) - y(:,i), i, 1, m);
```

Matlab returns the error:
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

m is length(y), X and y are matrices.

Comment: What is the value of `i`?

Comment: Don't use `symsum`.  That's used for **symbolic** math.  Replace `symsum` with `sum` and perhaps put this in a `for` loop looping for `i=1:m`.  `theta`, `X` and `y` look like numeric matrices.

Comment: @jukhamil - BTW, this looks like the cost function you use for linear regression via gradient descent or whatever method you're using to minimize this cost function.  Instead of looping, you can simply do: `J = (1/(2*m))*sum((X*theta - y).^2);` assuming that `X` is your data matrix where each row is a sample and each column is a variable and `y` are the ground truth values. All in all, don't use `symsum` here.

Comment: How will 'sum' understand to take the data matrix one column at a time? And, isn't the point of the syntax sum(form, var, a, b) so that we don't have to write a loop? (Var takes values from a to b)

Comment: You completely ignored what I said. `symsum` is for symbolic variables. You are using numeric matrices. You can't use it in any way shape or form because you are using the wrong type of data for it. You can use `sum` but you'll need to be careful about what you supply as an argument to it. Please see my previous comment.

Answer (score -5):

Not an expert in MatLab but most programming languages will return values in the type of the most precise operand.

In your case, (1 / (2*m)) is a floating point value, so all the remaining integers will be converted to floating point values in order to compute the result, and the result will be of that same type.

Comment: That's not correct.  The error in question is using the value of `i`.  You are assuming that the output can be computed, when in this case it can't.  In addition, the error returned is quite clear.  The keyword *subscript* refers to indexing into an array.  It has nothing to do with a computational error.  It is a type clash between numeric matrices and symbolic matrices here, not a difference between floating-point and integer.

Comment: Additionally, MATLAB's default data type is `double`, not `float`

Comment: rayryeng. Sorry, I missunderstood your question.

Comment: @SystemCrash - It isn't a problem.  Just be careful in providing an answer in the future.  Read the question carefully.  BTW, this isn't my question.  I just commented on your answer.